# CSS transition does not work on top property in FF

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, css-transitions

I have following HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <h2>title</h2>
        </a>
    </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
            <h2>title</h2>
        </a>
    </li>
     <li>
        <a href="#">
            <h2>title</h2>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style: none;  
    text-align: center;
}
ul li {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    width: 30%;
}
ul li {
    transition: all 0.3s;
}
ul li:hover {
    top: -10px;
}
ul li> a{
    color: red;
}
```

The question is the transition does not work with moz, it works on webkit. How do I implement this in a cross browser way?

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/am6xb/4/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Browsers don't apply `transition` on a property if an initial value for it is not specified in the element. Hence, adding `top: 0px` to `ul li` will solve the issue.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 20px;
  top: 0px; /* this line was added */
  width: 30%;
}
ul li {
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
ul li:hover {
  top: -10px;
}
ul li> a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Library included just to avoid prefixes so that users with older browser can view -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <h2>title</h2>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <h2>title</h2>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <h2>title</h2>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** I would also suggest using the same option (`transform`) as mentioned in Mr_Green's answer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why `top` css property is acting weird to do animation in firefox even it is listed as [*animation behaviour property*](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#properties-from-css-) in css.

Anyway, using `margin-top` instead of `top` is working fine in Firefox.

But I would like to suggest going with [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)'s "*translateX*" and "*translateY*" css properties instead of using positioning from next time because it is efficient. (*recommended by [Paul Irish](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)*)

Comment: I think if `top: 0px` is added to the original code, it would still work fine (not saying that is better, but it would work). I remember reading an answer on SO earlier which stated that FF doesn't apply transition when the property is not mentioned in the original element.

Comment: @Harry yeah that is right. just now realized. :) Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PRj3V/1/).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
ul li { 
    /* standard property and other vendor prefixes */
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
}
ul li:hover {
    /* standard property and other vendor prefixes */
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```

Comment: @Sam add `-moz-transition` vendor prefix and also don't remove `transition` css property. If you did the same then ignore this message.

Comment: @Mr_Green yes! Mr_green i tried that too.. i have updated the demo as wel

Comment: @Sam it seems the problem is with `top` css property. When I replaced `top` with `margin-top`. It is working fine.

Comment: then use this,ul li {
    
    
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s;
}
ul li:hover {
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
}

Comment: @Mr_Green Thank you. Could you post it as an aswer. Then I can accept it :)

Comment: Mr green's answer fits for you perfectly. your position:relative;top:-10px was telling FF to simply move your div relative -10px from its baseline, instead of animating it with what Mr. green suggested.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely not the transition declaration or anything else in the CSS you've written --- try adding `opacity:.5` to the hover state and you'll see it animate fine.

So, for some reason, Firefox is not transitioning the `top` property. To be honest, I don't know why yet. My solution for now would be to use a CSS transform to move the item up 10px instead:

```
ul li:hover {
    -o-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-10px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
```

}

This successfully animates in Firefox as you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/y7yQQ/7/

Comment: Thanks David, I am going to use margin-top instead of top :)

Comment: @Sam yeah, good point, that would achieve the same with a lot less CSS!