# Apply transition to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I have 3 `divs` positioned next to each other, and background `div`. We'll call the background `div` bg `div`. Whenever one of the 3 `divs` get selected, the bg `div` gets positioned on top of the selected `div`. (Basically, something like a segmented controller.)

When I try making the bg `div` transition to its new position. I did the following to transition:

```
transition: left linear .2s;
```

When you select a `div` for the first time, the animation doesn't happen, but the bg `div` does move over to its correct position (just without the animation). After the second click and on, it works.

How can I add a transition to the bg `div`?

#### JSFiddle

```js
$('.inner').click(function() {
  var pos = $(this).position();
  $("#back").css('left', pos.left + "px");
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.inner {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 50px;
}
#back {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  position: relative;
  transition: left linear 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">First Option</div>
  <div class="inner">Second Option</div>
  <div class="inner">Third Option</div>
  <div id="back"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440393/css-transition-does-not-work-on-top-property-in-ff/18441215#18441215. Set an initial value for the `left` property of `#back`. That thread indicates only FF but the reason is applicable for Webkit and others too.

Comment: just add left:0; to #back{left:0;}  http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/weaw5v3o/1/

Comment: @Harry I wouldn't call the question a duplicate because the actual question is different. It happens to be the answer stated there also works for me.

Comment: @Jessica: I disagree because the core reason is the same but I'd leave it to the community to vote on.

Comment: @Harry But yes. When I add `left:0` it works. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Harry You're right! The core problem is the same. I'm with you on this one! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a transition to take effect, there should be an initial value defined from which the animation would start.

Here `#back` does not have an initial `left` value due to which on the first click, it would jump directly to the `left` position defined on click.
This will take be the initial value for the next transition and hence from then on you would see the animation in transition.

So all you need to do is add `left:0px;` in css for `#back`.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `left: 0;` property for css  `#back`

```js
$('.inner').click(function() {
  var pos = $(this).position();
  $("#back").css('left', pos.left + "px");
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 30px;
  position: relative;
}
.inner {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 50px;
}
#back {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  position: relative;
  transition: left linear 1s;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="inner">First Option</div>
  <div class="inner">Second Option</div>
  <div class="inner">Third Option</div>
  <div id="back"></div>
</div>
```