# transition not showing without element in root class

Tags: css

I'm having the following setup:

```
#search-suggestion {
    @include transition(top 0.5s ease);
    left: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 1;

    &.visible {
        top: 66px;
    }

    &.notvisible {
        top: -200px;
    }
}
```

but the transition isn't working, this works however when I add the `top` element to the `#search-suggestion`. But then the functionality doesn't work as intended with the `.visible` and `.notvisible`;

adding the `@include transition(top 0.5s ease);` to the `.visible` and `.notvisible` doesn't work for the animations.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You mean it works only when you add a initial value for `top` property (or) do you have a separate `top` element? Can you post the compiled CSS and maybe a demo?

Comment: Also, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18440393/css-transition-does-not-work-on-top-property-in-ff/18441215#18441215. This could potentially be a duplicate depending on your answer to my previous comment.